# Pass JSON object from javascript client to Python app

Tags: javascript, python, json, sockets

I have a python application running locally listening on a socket for a JSON object.

I want to be able to connect to the python application by sending over a JSON object from the browser with javascript. What are the ways that this can be done? I think I should look into XHR or websockets for how to approach this problem but I'm not sure what the pros and cons of each options are.

I've tried sending over a JSON object using an AJAX post request but it does not seem to be working as I'd expect.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8888",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(object),
        success: function(result){...}
```

The python application is getting something but I'm unable to pull out the JSON data. This is the current output of the python application:

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:57.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
```

At the moment, I'm using `char = socket.recv(1)` to retrieve the data and outputting the results to screen. Do I need to fix my AJAX message or do I need to fix my python code? Or is there a larger picture I'm missing out on.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets have a persistent connection open and are for real-time communication. If you want a standard RESTful model, HTTP is what you need.

I'm not sure what Python web framework you are using, but most web frameworks should allow you to define a route where you can `POST` to and will help you convert the payload into an object to be used in the controller.

I would recommend that you look up some common examples of the Python framework you are using. Pretty sure they will have an example of how a POST request can be handled.

You do not need websockets here.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm not using any python framework per se. I'm opening an INET socket connection and want to send JSON data over to the python server with a javascript front end. It doesn't seem like that's possible without websockets, right? Sorry, I'm not really familiar with sockets in general.